# Constructing an object as part of ostream output

Tags: c++11, object, ostream, construction

For a class declaration as below:

```
class A{
public:
A(int);
~A()
private:
int a;
};
```

And a constructor definition as follows:

```
A::A(int i){
 a = i;
 cout << a << endl;
}
```

I would like to do something like this from main():

```
int main(){
int i;
//user input for value
//stored inside i
cout << "The value is " << A obj(i);
return 0;
}
```

I now get the following error for the above code in main():

> error: 'A' does not refer to a value

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare `obj` and output it on the same line. If you want `obj` to remain available after printing, do this:

```
A obj(i);
cout << "The value is " << obj;
```

Otherwise, skip `obj` in favor of a temporary object:

```
cout << "The value is " << A(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a declaration in the middle of another line.

What you *can* do is create an A on the fly with casting `(A) i`, or simply `A(i)`, this will cast the int `i` into an A, and then send it to `cout`. The temporary A object is then directly discarded.

If you want to keep it, you have to declare a name for it, in its own statement.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That does not work, since I get the error "invalid operands to binary" for using A(i) with cout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first output the message "The value is " on first code line. On the second code line you create the object obj of type A which will output the i.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    cout << "The value is ";
    A obj(i);
    return 0;
}
```